# Flot chart in Bootstrap not sizing correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flot

So I added a Flot chart to my page with Bootstrap 3 CSS styling. The chart looks great at medium and large resolutions. However, when I set my browser to a smaller screensize, the chart automatically changes to use only 6 columns or half the container. On the same page, the text in the "col-sm-12" works correctly and takes up all 12 columns. Only the chart is taking up only 6 columns. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
<div id="page-chart" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    Chart goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or working example?

Comment: If you could add your HTML, it would be easier to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about including the [resize](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/resize/) plugin?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
```

See this [example](http://www.bootply.com/vbCvSA1KDz).